# Android How to get number ending

Tags: android

in my project I get a list of items and I have to write on the list item his number, with a "number ending", for example :

1st , 2nd , 3rd and so on, the list is very long.

is there a proper way to set the number ending?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public String NumberWithSuffix(int number) {
        if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("11")) return String.valueOf(number) + "th";
        if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("12")) return String.valueOf(number) + "th";
        if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("13")) return String.valueOf(number) + "th";
        if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("1")) return String.valueOf(number) + "st";
        if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("2")) return String.valueOf(number) + "nd";
        if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("3")) return String.valueOf(number) + "rd";
        return String.valueOf(number) + "th";
    }
```

optimized code.

```
 public String NumberWithSuffix(int number) {

        String outputNumber = "";
        String numberString = String.valueOf(number);

        if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("11")) {
            outputNumber = numberString + "th";
        } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("12")) {
            outputNumber = numberString + "th";
        } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("13")) {
            outputNumber = numberString + "th";
        } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("1")) {
            outputNumber = numberString + "st";
        } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("2")) {
            outputNumber = numberString + "nd";
        } else if(String.valueOf(number).endsWith("3")) {
            outputNumber = numberString + "rd";
        } else {
            outputNumber = numberString + "th";
        }
        return outputNumber;
    }
```

Comment: Upvoted.... but it could be optimized with a single `return` statement (functions should have a `single exit point`).